# Can batch search requests be sent to the Google Custom Search API?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

My application is crossing the allowance of Google's limits for their custom search API. In looking to optimize my search calls, I was wondering, is there a way to batch search requests sent to the API? I have some pages that make multiple requests per user search, and would like to batch them into one API call. I've looked around a fair bit, and haven't been able to find anything, so I wanted to check if anyone else had managed to figure it out before moving on to other optimizations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Custom search is geared towards interactive use and batch requests are not supported.