# Unable to get results more than 100 results on google custom search api

Tags: google-api, search-engine, google-custom-search

I need to use Google Custom Search API https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview. From that page, it said:

> For CSE users, the API provides 100 search queries per day for free.
>   If you need more, you may sign up for billing in the Developers
>   Console. Additional requests cost $5 per 1000 queries, up to 10k
>   queries per day.

I already sign up for billing inside the developer console. However, I still could not retrieve results more than 100. What things should I do more? https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?cx=CSE_INSTANCE&key=API_KEY&q=QUERY&start=100

> { error: { errors: [ { domain: "global", reason: "invalid", message:
>   "Invalid Value" } ], code: 400, message: "Invalid Value" } }

Answer (score 4):

Query: Definition
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/1361951

> Any actual user query from a Google Site Search engine, including but
>   not limited to search engines installed on your website using XML,
>   iFrame, or the Custom Search Element.

That means you would probably need to send eleven **queries** to get more than 100 **results**.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?&q=QUERY&...&start=1
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?&q=QUERY&...&start=11
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?&q=QUERY&...&start=21
GET ...
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?&q=QUERY&...&start=81
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?&q=QUERY&...&start=91 
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?&q=QUERY&...&start=101
```

Check every response and if `error` `code` is `400`, you can stop - there is probably no need to send next (`&start=`previous+10) request.

Now you can merge responses and start building results page.

> Google Custom Search and Google Site Search return up to 10 results
>   per query. If you want to display more than 10 results to the user,
>   you can issue multiple requests (using the start=0, start=11 ...
>   parameters) and display the results on a single page. In this case,
>   Google will consider each request as a separate query, and if you are
>   using Google Site Search, each query will count towards your limit.

There might be a better way to do this then I described above. (But, I'm not sure about [batching API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405747/can-batch-search-requests-be-sent-to-the-google-custom-search-api).)

And (finally) possible answer to your question: I made more than few tests, but I haven't had any luck with `start` greater than 100 (I was getting the same as you - `<Response [400]>`). I'm using "Browser key" from my billing-enabled project. [That could mean we can't get 101st, 102nd, 103rd, etc.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/customsearch/%22more$20than$20100%22%7Csort:date) results with CSE API.

Comment: On my request, I could see totalResults is 97400. However, I could not get results more than 100 records.

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: Not sure about you, but I think I should completely rewrite my answer. It's plain wrong, sorry. And I don't have any good news, sorry again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Never mind. What i wonder is that when I go to https://cse.google.com/cse/all, I still see it's "Free edition". Do you have any idea?

Comment: When you **enable billing** on "free edition", then you have more than 100 queries (via JSON/Atom Custom Search API) per day available on that engine - you can set your own limits. With [Google Site Search](https://www.google.com/work/search/products/gss.html#pricing_content) **subscription** (based on the number of queries per year), you get "paid edition" and [advanced Site Search features](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4541888). (Those are two different pricing models - subscription and pay as you go.)

Comment: I am facing the same problem too. Do you know a way to fix this? Or does Google deliberately restricts maximum number of search results as 100 for each query??

Comment: i am facing the same issue as well.

Comment: Query successfully for `start=91`, but fail for `start>=101` even though there are 230 results.

Comment: This is old but according to the docs: "The JSON API will never return more than 100 results, even if more than 100 documents match the query, "

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation says it never returns more than 100 items.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list

> **start**
> *integer (uint32 format)*
>
> The index of the first result to return. The default number of results
> per page is 10, so &start=11 would start at the top of the second page
> of results. Note: The JSON API will never return more than 100
> results, even if more than 100 documents match the query, so setting
> the sum of start + num to a number greater than 100 will produce an
> error. Also note that the maximum value for num is 10.

Comment: This is correct and if we could iterate to the millions and billions then we could dump out the entire google index and that might not be a good thing for google. ◉_◉