# Google Custom Search: How To Show More Than 10 results for the Public URL (View it on the web) option

Tags: search-engine, google-search, google-custom-search

This is a total beginner question.
I created a Custom Search under cse.google.com/cse/all for a specific website...

I want to use the Public URL (View it on the web) feature. (not the api option)

How can I modify the generated custom search in a way that I get more than just 10 results per page?
It would be great to increase the number of results to at least 100 (like on the generic google search).

Within the Control Panel (Modify your search engine) I did not find the specific variable.

There is an answer to a variation of that question but it's about api and I'm not sure how to apply this to the Public URL (View it on the web) option. 
[Unable to get results more than 100 results on google custom search api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633466/unable-to-get-results-more-than-100-results-on-google-custom-search-api)

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can set "Result Size" in the Control Panel under Search features -> Advanced -> WebSearch Restricts
You can select up to 20 results per page.